# Python import error in eclipse (Package works in command line but not eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, tweepy

I'm having trouble importing tweepy. I've looked through so many previous questions and still can't find a correct solution. I think it has something to do with how tweepy is being downloaded when I install but I'm not sure. I get an import error saying that "tweepy is not a package".

I have tweepy library connected to the interpreter and all that but, it is saved as a compressed EGG file instead of a file folder like the rest of my packages. I think that has something to do with it but I'm not too sure.

Also, tweepy works in my command line but not in eclipse.

Comment: Please be more specific - what do you mean by "works"? It does not do auto-completion for you or when you start it from eclipse it does not or it highlights the import of the package as `Unresolved import`?

Answer (score 0):

If you recently installed the package maybe just reconfigure your pydev (`Window`->`Preferences`->`PyDev`->`Interpreters`->`Python Interpreter`: `Quick Auto Configure`).